# pass a url as parameter to Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, encodeuricomponent

Hi I need to pass a url as a parameter to a laravel route, but it gives me a 404 error. I tried to send the url as an encoded string and it's still not working. My code:

```
 var search = encodeURIComponent($('#links_search').val());
```

and the ajax call sent to

```
api/v1/clicks/p/'+page_num+'/'+search
```

I'm searching URL's in db, and the Laravel Route is defined as follows

```
Route::get('/clicks/p/{page?}/{search?}',
        [
           'as' => 'allClicksUrl',
           'uses' => 'ApiController@getAllClicks'
        ]);
```

Any suggestions to this requirement?

Comment: why did you use `?` mark ? Can you please explain

Comment: @Jahid26 It means "optional parameter".

Comment: @Jahid26 ,it means its optional, it can accept empty value also

Comment: You're sending to `/api/v1/clicks/...` but the route is `/clicks/...`. Is that route inside a group with a prefix or similar?

Comment: Hi yes the api routes have a prefix as :  Route::group(['prefix' => '/api/v1'], function () {

Comment: This is working if i sent Base64 Encoded string. !

Comment: @chasenyc this is different question.  passing a url as a parameter. for e.g api/v1/clicks/p/1/[some url]

Comment: @Vigikaran do you have some custom Request in your `getAllClicks` method?

Comment: No there is no custom request